# Refactoring: Move up in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ipad

As I understand it, a move up transformation (?) will move a method or property or variable from a subclass to it's superclass? However I haven't worked out what I need to select for the Move Up to become selectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've use the following method to Move Up variables and methods but not properties in Xcode 3.2.5.  Select the token identifying the variable or method.  Don't select any of the type information.  You can select the method from either the .h or .m file.

Be sure that if you have just added the variable or method to the file to save it first or the Refactor option won't be enabled.

For example, you can select "s" or "foo" below:

```
@interface Sub : Parent
{
    NSString * s;
}
- (void) foo;
```